# Failed to install google-assistant-sdk[samples] to raspberry pi Zero W

Tags: python, raspberry-pi, setup.py, google-assistant-sdk

I am attempting to install the Google Assistant to a raspberry pi Zero W.

During the last step it to failed to complete install google-assistant-sdk[samples].

I am running python 3.9.2 on the pi Zero. Python 3 is also loaded.

I have loaded the following to my Pi Zero as part of the setup for running the assistant, per the Google Assistant SDK setup instructions.

```
sudo apt-get update
sudo apt-get install python3-dev python3-venv
python3 -m venv env
env/bin/python -m pip install --upgrade pip setuptools wheel
```

Then I activated the virtual env

```
source env/bin/activate
```

In the virtual env I loaded

```
sudo apt-get install portaudio19-dev libffi-dev libssl-dev
```

The final step requires loading the Google assistant SDK, this is where it goes wrong.

```
python -m pip install --upgrade google-assistant-sdk[samples]
```

Initially the setup seems to be going well, then while preparing the metadata after downloading grpcio-1.47.0.tar.gz the subprocess exits with an error.

```
Collecting grpcio>=1.3.5
  Downloading grpcio-1.47.0.tar.gz (21.9 MB)
     ━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━ 21.9/21.9 MB 627.2 kB/s eta 0:00:00
  Preparing metadata (setup.py) ... error
  error: subprocess-exited-with-error

  × python setup.py egg_info did not run successfully.
  │ exit code: 1
  ╰─> [14 lines of output]
      Traceback (most recent call last):
        File "<string>", line 2, in <module>
        File "<pip-setuptools-caller>", line 34, in <module>
        File "/tmp/pip-install-07egyhge/grpcio_4430b3443c8b44d5b7610d4106a35227/setup.py", line 263, in <module>
          if check_linker_need_libatomic():
        File "/tmp/pip-install-07egyhge/grpcio_4430b3443c8b44d5b7610d4106a35227/setup.py", line 219, in check_linker_need_libatomic
          cpp_test = subprocess.Popen(
        File "/usr/lib/python3.9/subprocess.py", line 951, in __init__
          self._execute_child(args, executable, preexec_fn, close_fds,
        File "/usr/lib/python3.9/subprocess.py", line 1698, in _execute_child
          and os.path.dirname(executable)
        File "/usr/lib/python3.9/posixpath.py", line 152, in dirname
          p = os.fspath(p)
      TypeError: expected str, bytes or os.PathLike object, not list
      [end of output]

  note: This error originates from a subprocess, and is likely not a problem with pip.
error: metadata-generation-failed

× Encountered error while generating package metadata.
╰─> See above for output.

note: This is an issue with the package mentioned above, not pip.
hint: See above for details.
```

I have rerun this several times, still in the virtual env, specifying either python3 or python3.9

```
python3 -m pip install --upgrade google-assistant-sdk[samples]

python3.9 -m pip install --upgrade google-assistant-sdk[samples]
```

I get the same error everytime.

At this point I am not sure what I can do differently.

I am looking for some guidance on next steps.

Thanks
manderson96

Answer (score 0):

Whilst it's not directly related to your issue above, this post at the end fixed it for me. There is an issue in the 1.46/47 builds, and you need to do some workarounds to install. Use Step 1 and 2, the further steps are not applicable.

https://github.com/home-assistant/core/issues/65837#issuecomment-1173134862

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).